# Sentinel node in doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I'm working on implementing my own doubly linked list. I have decided to use sentinel node at the end of the list which will store pointer to the last node in the list and the last node will store pointer to the sentinel node. Is this a good approach or the sentinel node should be used in different way? My code:

```
template <class T>
class MyList
{
public:
    MyList() : m_first(nullptr), m_last(nullptr), m_sentinel(new Node()) {}

    ~MyList()
    {
        delete m_sentinel;
    }

    void push_back(const T & data);
    void pop_back();
    void push_front(const T & data);
    void pop_front();

    class iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        if(m_first == nullptr) return iterator(m_sentinel);
        return iterator(m_first);

    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(m_sentinel);
    }
private:
    struct Node;

    Node * m_first;
    Node * m_last;
    Node * m_sentinel;
};

template <class T>
struct MyList<T>::Node
{
    Node() : m_data(nullptr), m_next(nullptr), m_prev(nullptr) {}
    Node(T * data, Node * next, Node * prev) : m_data(data), m_next(next), m_prev(prev) {}
    ~Node() { delete m_data; delete m_prev; }

    T * m_data;
    Node * m_next;
    Node * m_prev;
};
```

Comment: That's not my understanding of why you'd use a sentinel node for a linked list. My understanding is that you'd use one for a circular linked list. If it's not circular, the sentinel node is just adding unnecessary complexity. Especially since you already have pointers to your first and last nodes.

Comment: I can see the usage of a last node, so as to utilize fast appending to the back of the list.  But for an additional sentinel node, I don't see the utility for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a way to use a sentinel node, but ask yourself: what makes the *last* node special in a *doubly*-linked list? A doubly-linked list has symmetry; forward and backward look the same, modulo some naming differences. Putting a sentinel node after the last node breaks this symmetry, *unless you also put a sentinel node before the first node*.

So let's put another sentinel node before the first node. But hold on – why do we need *two* sentinel nodes? The sentinel after the last has a requirement on its "previous" pointer, while the sentinel before the first has a requirement on its "next" pointer. These requirements are not contradictory; they could be satisfied by a single sentinel node. If you use a single sentinel node, you get a circular doubly-linked list, with the sentinel node marking both the beginning and the end.

Time to ratchet things up another level. What is the purpose of the pointers to the first and last nodes? More to the point, what benefit does `m_first` have over `m_sentinel->m_next`? Well, the latter does have an extra level of indirection. If we deal with that, `MyList` would need to track only the sentinel node. Hmmm...

```
template <class T>
class MyList
{
public:
    MyList() : m_sentinel() { m_sentinel.m_next = m_sentinel.m_prev = &m_sentinel; }

    ~MyList() { /* Empty for now, but see the text after the code. */ }

    /* Public API omitted */

private:
    struct Node {
        /* Definition omitted in this illustration. */
        /* Needing the definition here instead of later in the file is one drawback. */
    };

    Node * first() { return m_sentinel.m_next; }
    Node * last()  { return m_sentinel.m_prev; }

    Node m_sentinel;  // <-- not a pointer!
};
```

This version of `MyList` has the same size as yours (it consists of three pointers), but makes better use of the sentinel node to simplify adding nodes to and removing nodes from the list. I'll note that one detail that helps this work is that your nodes store pointers to data instead of storing the data directly inside the node. So, as usual, the choice of which implementation to use comes down to analyzing the pros and cons.

If you do go this route, you will run into an oddity in how you manage memory. You've made each node responsible for deleting other nodes. This can be problematic for long lists, as you could exhaust the stack space (`~Node()` calls `~Node()` for the previous node before exiting, so your call stack grows linearly with the number of nodes). It's also non-idiomatic since a node is not responsible for creating other nodes. As a rule of thumb, the object that creates the nodes should be responsible for making sure they are destroyed. That is, don't have a `delete` without a corresponding `new` *at the same level*. Shift the responsibility for destroying nodes to `~MyList()` where the nodes can be iteratively disposed of, rather than recursively.

Comment: +1: The passage from the symmetry of the doubly-linked list to the use of a single sentinel node is very well exposed. I would add that the requirements on the sentinel node's pointers are also _complementary_.